# Limiting items to be shown in recyclerview

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am using a recyclerview inside a fragment to show items from a remote MySQL database.

Currently the database table has 4 items, but the recyclerview repeats the items continuosly.

I would like to shown the items only once.

This is the piece of code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addresses, container, false);


    //getData();



    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    getAddressesFromDB(0);

    gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);

    adapter = new AddressesAdapter(getActivity(), addresses);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "NUM ADDRESSES: " + addresses.size());
            if (gridLayout.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == addresses.size() - 1) {
                getAddressesFromDB(addresses.get(addresses.size() - 1).getId_address());
            }

        }
    });




    return view;
}
private void getAddressesFromDB(int id) {

    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://xxxx/android_addresses_api/direcciones_todas.php?id=" + addressesIds[0])
                    .build();
            try {
                okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                    Address address = new Address(object.getInt("id_address"), object.getString("cia"),
                            object.getString("fn"), object.getString("ln"),
                            object.getString("ad1"),object.getString("ad2"),object.getString("type"),
                            object.getString("city"),object.getString("state"),object.getString("zip"),
                            object.getString("phone"),object.getString("ext"),object.getInt("fromto"),
                            object.getString("user"));

                    addresses.add(address);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute(id);
}
```

And this is the PHP file.

```
<?php 
    //Creating a connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("X","X","X","X");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    /*Get the id of the last visible item in the RecyclerView from the request and store it in a variable. For            the first request id will be zero.*/  
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $sql= "Select * from tb_direcciones where id_address between ($id+1) and ($id+10)";

    $result = mysqli_query($con ,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $array[] = $row;

    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');

    echo json_encode($array);

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Comment: you show data using scrolllistener that's why duplicate data

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, and how should I change the code to show only once the existing items, scrolling only if needed?

Comment: you need to check if recyclerview scroll to last item at bottom then again call api with increse page number to load more data

Comment: or just remove scroll listener if not needed and put  getAddressesFromDB(addresses.get(addresses.size() - 1).getId_address()); code in onCreateView after recycler initialization

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, removing the scrolllistener part solves my issue, I have added more items and they are shown as expected

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, would you mind to put that as answer, I mean where should I put getAddressesFromDB(addresses.get(addresses.size() - 1).getId_address());

Comment: does getAddressesFromDB(0); fetch all records from DB?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel, yes it does

Comment: then you are already calling that and filling Recyclerview.no need for extra code. just remove whole scrolllistenr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are already calling that and filling Recyclerview.no need for extra code. just remove whole scrolllistenr